# What is the best way to implement wait or websocket response

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, asp.net-core-7.0

`
i implemented async await method to get relevent socket, i did it with  Task.Delay

is there better implementation to get result when socket just arrived and without Task.Delay`

i save all sockets responses in dictionary

```
WebSocket socket;

await sSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(binaryMessage, 0, binaryMessage.Length), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

var result = await GetSocketResult(requestId);


private Dictionary<string,SocketResult> socketsResults { get; set; } = new();

     private async Task<string> GetSocketResult(string requestId)
        {
            byte maxSec = 60;
            byte counter = 0;
            byte skip = 2;

            do
            {
                string json = string.Empty;
                if(socketsResults.TryGetValue(requestId, out var res))
                {
                    json = res.Json;    
                }
               
                if (res != null)
                {
                    socketsResults.Remove(res.RequestId);

                    // remove old sockets
                    _ = Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        var dt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1);
                        foreach (var item in socketsResults)
                        {
                            if (item.Value.Created > dt)
                            {
                                socketsResults.Remove(item.Key);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    return json;
                }
                counter += skip;
                await Task.Delay(skip * 1000);
            } while (counter < maxSec);

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using delay you should implement something along the lines of the following.

```
var task = Task.Run(() => stuff);
await Task.WhenAll(task);
//next step
```

Then you can call `await GetSocketResult(...)` or `GetSocketResult(...).Wait()` depending on the use case.

Comment: my server receive all kinds of sockets request/responses,
when the socket is of type response, i add the response to socketsResults dictionary,
because of this your code will not work.
what i need is code that wait x seconds until the response socket with the correct request id is added to socketsResults.